# How do I host a web application on AWS for worldwide use while following the Data Protection Laws for Germany & European Union?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, data-protection

We are building an application that stores email and phone numbers of the users. We understand that German data privacy laws require the database and web services to be hosted in Germany (i.e. a data centre in Germany). Our AWS EC2 instance is hosted in us-west. Do we need to host the application on the German data centre as well? We are using PHP5 with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

The German privacy law requires you to store and compute personal data in data centers located in the EU. So you are able to use eu-west-1 (Ireland) and eu-central-1 (Germany) on AWS at the moment.

But this tackles only one of the technical requirements you need to fulfill to be compliant with the German privacy law. There are other technical and non-technical requirements as well (e.g. an agreeement called Auftragsdatenverarbeitungsvereinbarung, not using global AWS services, ...).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. Regional data must be stored within a data center located in that region. For instance, I have an application that is mainly hosted in US East, but I have customers in Ireland, Sydney, and Japan so I have deployments in those regions as well.

Your best bet is to either intimately familiarize yourself with the data laws in countries you are targeting, or hire a lawyer that can help you through it. You do not want to be on the receiving end of a lawsuit for mishandling customer data!